# Open as a pop up box when clicked on show button in meteor

Tags: meteor

I need to open up a pop up box on click of a button "show". I am using meteor 1.1.9. Anybody knows how could I do it with meteor?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open modal here's a simple example

**test.html**

```
<div style="float:right;  margin: 10px 40px;">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-info  open-insert-modal" value="Data Insert" data-backdrop="false"></div>
<div id="insertModal" class="modal fade" style="margin-left: 25%;margin-top: 10%;width: 50%;">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">InsertData</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <!-- body code -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**test.js**

```
'click .open-insert-modal': function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //{backdrop: "static"} it is use for only close button click than close
    $('#insertModal').modal({backdrop: "static"});
},
```

Comment: I would like to know for using tags like **"data-dismiss"** or **"aria-hidden"**, do I need any plugins to be added in the Meteor? Because as I try to use these tags, nothing happens.I tried Bipin's code as a sample but could not see any modal(jquery pop up) opening.

Comment: user1662039 paste the code you have wrote so we can see what's wrong.

Comment: Sorry for that you can add  meteor add twbs:bootstrap

Comment: I do not have the provision to add the plugins as I work under proxy and that limits the command to add plugins. May I know if there is another way to work this out?

Answer (score 0):

My code is below
**test.html**

```
<template name="modal">  
   <div style="float:right;  margin: 10px 40px;">
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-info  open-insert-modal" value="Data Insert" data-backdrop="false">
   </div>
   <div id="insertModal" class="modal fade" style="margin-left:25%;margin-top: 10%;width: 50%;">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">InsertData</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</template>
```

**test.js**

```
Template.body.events({  
  'click .open-insert-modal': function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
     //{backdrop: "static"} it is use for only close button click than close
       $('#insertModal').modal({backdrop: "static"});
  },
  });
```

This is the same code as posted by Bipin which I am trying to test for opening up pop up window similar to jQuery pop up windows.